# Mobile Device Management Feasibility in android based on these concept

Tags: android, mobile, enterprise, mdm

As we know We have Two devices for **MDM** like one **Master Device** and **One Slave Device**.

Though i am So new to this MDM platform i need to know these things are possible in android or not, please please please help me out of this.

*Points are*

1.**Lock with a PIN** - can a master device will be able to lock the slave device.

2.**Record Audio**-If needed the slave device will give 1 min recording to master device.

3.**Take a Picture and Record a Video**-Same Description as audio requirement.

4.**Activity Log**-The MDM app on the slave device should keep a usage log (overall usage of the device and also usage of each APP).

5.**List of Apps**-The slave device needs to be able to report all APPs installed.

6.**Handling time changes on the device**-Master Device has the access to changing the time on the slave devices.

7.**Usage Limiter**-Example of use: Master Deivce sets up a rule which will allow usage of the slave device from 10am to 4pm, however only 2 hours of usage are allowed within the usage window. The MDM APP needs to keep track of activity of the device and discount time from the two hours. Once the two hours are reached, the device locks itself again.

> Please let me know if these things are possible in android or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are several MDM's available in market.
 One of them are SOTI. SOTI can be used for most of the requirements that you are looking for.

- SOTI gives us the option to write scripts and run it to control features of the slave device.
- Number of slave's getting connected, files to be synced from server by specifying path
- Manupulating device timestamp with desired timestamp
- Remotely view screen and user interaction happening in slave device
- Remotely lock the slave device with pin or password all these are possible.

  Please go through this link [SOTI FEATURES LINK](http://www.soti.net/products/mobicontrol/key-features/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes, providing there is audio recording software already installed (no hidden audio recording)
3. Yes, using standard Android apps (no hidden recording)
4. Yes, recommend to connect via sales@soti.net
5. Yes, core functionality of MobiControl
6. Yes
7. Yes, can specific during time of day when device is unlocked. Example, 2 - 4pm EST unlocked, all other hours it is locked. We do not keep a running count of total hours unlocked before locking.

Sueanne - SOTI

Comment: Thank you but i want to know one thing how to get into it i mean have to register on SOTI or what?